# Spark Scala Why is it that I can make certain function calls with parenthesis and certain function calls without parenthesis

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jvm

I've been working with Spark having just a basic understanding of Scala and I noticed that I can do both

```
df.groupBy("c1").count.show
```

and

```
df.groupBy("c1").count().show()
```

Both will produce the same result. When can I use parenthesis for function calls and when can I not? What is the reason for this?

Comment: @werner So, would my example be infix, postfix or prefix?

Comment: If a a no parameter method is defined as `def abc(): String` then it can be used as either `abc()` or just `abc`. But, if this was defined as `def abc: String` then it can only be used as `abc`.